# What's the difference between ATIS and D-ATIS?

Tags: air-traffic-control, atis

What's the difference between the two? Do you need a special digital VHF radio to receive D-ATIS broadcasts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ATIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_terminal_information_service) is traditionally a voice recording of someone reading the weather. D-ATIS is a way to deliver the information digitally so onboard equipment can interact with it. [From the requirements](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7032.13.pdf)

> Digital ATIS is an enhancement of the Tower Data Link Service (TDLS)
>   and uses the Pre-Departure Clearance (PDC) System microcomputer to
>   automate the delivery of airport and terminal area operational and
>   meteorological information to aircraft flightcrews.
>   Two phases of development are planned. The first phase will provide,
>   via data link, a digital version of the ATIS /4 to flightcrews. Voice
>   recording will continue to be utilized in the preparation of the ATIS
>   broadcast. The second phase will add automated voice generation for
>   the ATIS broadcasts.

Its part of a [larger data link system](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/acf/media/Presentations/15-01_RD289_Data_Comm_Briefing_Anderson.pdf) that allows aircrafts and controllers to communicate certain things (weather info, clearances etc) with out clogging the radio channel.

Some ATIS systems now have a voice synthesizer reading out the reports so that no one needs to manually update the recording every hour.